# Cursors changes

Tags: java, svg, canvas, batik

I have a question about treating cursor manipulation.
In the JFrame in which I work there are different types of Jpanel, JComboBox, SVGcanvas, etc...
In each of them the cursor is different but its type depends on the previous actions and other elements as where it comes from and what has been done the elements before. 
I am wondering if there is an existing abstract pattern to solve this case, and how would you recommend to treat this problem.
Of course today I use MouseListener in conjunction with flags, but it is quite complicated.

Comment: Code? Your best bet is to draw a state machine that has all your transitions, and then code that (easy). You're swing events are not guaranteed - so you should never assume you are in the right state, but call setCursor based on your FSM result (if there is a state change) on mouse moved.

Comment: A state machine ! Good idea !

Comment: If you think so, up vote please.